# Using a certificate with requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a website which asks me to login. It's a blog website which I would like to automatically publish stuff. I use python and the `requests` package.

```
blog_url = "PATH/TO/BLOG"
r = requests.get(tapuz_post_url)
print(r.content)
```

Unfortunately the website does not have API. After running the script I get:

```
in send raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='BLOG', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: PATH/TO/BLOG (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

So I have two questions:

1. Where I can find the certificate or how to create one?
2. What is the right way to pass the certificate when requesting?

Comment: I think this might be happening because of an outdated version of `pyOpenSSL`. can you run `pip freeze | grep pyOpenSSL` and post the output?

Comment: Is the website giving SSL error when you visit it through browser?

Comment: It not. The website link: "http://www.tapuz.co.il/Blogs/Admin#postsListWindow#editPostWindow"